# Binding conflict after update of Xamarin and MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I recently switches to the Xamarin beta channel and upgraded my project to the latest MvvmCross release (V4.2.3). After that I am noticing that there are a couple of warnings during the build:

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:

There is also a dump of the assemblys causing the conflict (all .NET system assemblys and Newtonsoft.JSON):

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the warning aside of clicking on the warning? This won't work and the warning will appear anyway. My app is working but I can't estimate the trouble that warning will summon in the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.RegularExpressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encoding" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Debug" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Requests" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Concurrent" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq.Expressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Globalization" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.XDocument" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Dynamic.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: What is the detailed warning in the build output?